# Why is Python running a file twice when I only ran it once with the exec() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I am trying to create a mod loading program, and one of the methods that I tried to do is to use the `exec()` function I found out about. I have tried to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434492/why-python-print-my-output-two-times-when-i-import-the-same-file-in-which-i-am-p) question here on Stack Overflow to solve my problem, but the answer to that question is to not import the module to itself (which I'm not doing, as far as I know).

## Code

### Expected Output

```
['example']
Hello World!
```

### What I See

```
['example']
Hello World!
['example']
Hello World!
```

### `main.py`

```py
import os
import types

MODSDIR = 'Welder/mods/'

mods = []
ignoredFiles = ["__init__.py", "__pycache__"]
files = os.listdir(MODSDIR)

def register(mod):
    try:
        mods.append(mod)
    except:
        print("Welder.error.ERROR: mod ID must be type 'str'")

'''
for fileIndex in range(len(files)):
    importFileName = ""
    fileName = files[fileIndex]

    for char in fileName:
        if not char == ".":
            importFileName += char
        else:
            break

    if not fileName in ignoredFiles:
        mods.append(importFileName)
'''

exec(open("Welder/mods/example.py").read())

mods = list(set(mods))  # Removes weirdly added duplicates
print(mods)

printHello()
```

### `example.py`

```py
from main import mods

def printHello():
    print("Hello World!")

mods.append("example")
```

Comment: You forgot to describe what actually _happens_ - do you get a stackoverflow exception, an import error, unexpected duplicate output? Something else? We can't see your screen  :)

Comment: `from main import mods` runs `mods.py`, so that would be expected. Anyway, the real question is: whatever you're doing, why aren't you using the well built import system rather than using ugly hacks around `exec`?

Comment: The way I want the mod loader to work is that anyone who is coding a mod, they need to add the mods' "ID" to the `mods` list, so then it can run it with the `exec()` function.

Comment: Also, `mods` is a list, not a file.

Comment: @Tiimzy Try to put `if __name__ == "__main__":` in `main.py`

Comment: Thank you so much!! It makes it work only once now! :DD

Comment: When you import from main in example.py you do all the work in main.py a second time unless you use the  guard @AndrejKesely suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the output twice because the python interpreter opens and runs main.py twice;

- First when running `python main.py`
- A second time when example.py imports main.py via `from main import mods`

Each time main.py is interpreted , `printHello()` is then called.

To prevent the second time, you can replace the last 4 lines in main.py with;

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    exec(open("Welder/mods/example.py").read())

    mods = list(set(mods))  # Removes weirdly added duplicates
    print(mods)

    printHello()
```